# How to remove or handle icons were reregistered warning in react?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluentui-react

warning-
 `react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Some icons were re-registered. Applications should only call registerIcons for any given icon once. Redefining what an icon is may have unintended consequences. Duplicates include:  GlobalNavButton, ChevronDown, ChevronUp, Edit, Add, Cancel, More, Settings, Mail, Filter (+ 3592 more)`
Is there any way to compile and remove this warning.

Answer (score 2):

import { setIconOptions } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Styling";

// Suppress icon warnings.
setIconOptions({
disableWarnings: true,
});

Comment: but i want to remove this warning and supress it